# display data in multiple columns

Tags: php, javascript, sql, css

Hi I need to build a table with four columns from a mySQL table.
Here is what i have now:

```
 <?php

 "<table>";
     while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result , MYSQL_ASSOC) )
     {
         "<tr>";
         "<td>";         
           print("<p><img id='g1' src='/$row[img]' width=130 height=130 onClick='f1()'>" );  
           print( "<p> Name: $row[name] <br>");    
          "</td>";
      "</tr>";
        "</table>";
           }


  ?>
```

the output will be one column table like this:

[image]

I need the table to be in four columns like this:

[image]

Is this possible if it is how do I do that?

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, not layout.  You would have to place one book per row in order for this to be an appropriate use of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$items_in_row = 4 ;
$index = 0 ;
?>

<table>
  <tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result , MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
  $index++ ; ?>
  <td>       
    <p>
      <img id='g1' src='/<?php echo $row["img"] ;?>' width=130 height=130 onClick='f1()'>" ; 
    </p>
    <p> Name: <?php echo $row['name'] ; ?> </p>
    <br>
  </td>
<?php if ($index%$items_in_row == 0){ ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<?php }
} ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Edited**

Comment: when I render the page in browser I got Warning: Division by zero in line 110 , line 110 is <?php if ($index%$items_per_row == 0){ ?>

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `<tr>`s to *outside* the `while`.

```
"<table><tr>";
while ($row = ...) {
    "<td>";
    ...
    "</td>";
}
"</tr></table>";
```

I assume this is some sort of pseudocode as you don't actually write the string to anything.  You should also not use the `mysql_` functions in new code, but use PDO or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
"<table>";
"<tr>";
 $i=1;
 while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result , MYSQL_ASSOC) )
 {         
      "<td>";         
       print("<p><img id='g1' src='/$row[img]' width=130 height=130 onClick='f1()'>" );  
       print( "<p> Name: $row[name] <br>");    
      "</td>";
      if ($i%4 == 0){
          "</tr><tr>"
      }
      $i++;
    "</tr>"
    "</table>";
       }
```